# Google Play blank screen loading forever Internal Testing and Public Alpha track

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

There's no crash in Logcat.

Both releases were created 24 hours ago.

Public Alpha (closed) track
https://photos.app.goo.gl/mm9DKDDyqkfb4Y6S6

Internal Testing track
https://photos.app.goo.gl/wC95MMdhqzCTrSr9A

P.S.: Would have loved to file a bug report but found no appropriate channel.

Comment: same for me.. any update on this?

Comment: me too, same isue

Comment: same thing happening to me as well. Still no response after 24 hours

Comment: Shocked at how little documentation there is to this.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, I have tried all the proposed answers and double checked the settings on play console but still when I try to open the link to play store on my device play store seems to enter an endless loop of loading, gives neither timeout or any other error.

Answer (score 19):

I managed to fix this by **enabling the internal app sharing** option on the play store account I wanted to test the app before accessing the link.
Just `open your playstore`, `click on settings`, `enable developer mode` (by tapping seven times on the Play Store Version) and then enable the `internal app sharing`.

If it doesn't work, you could change the permissions on "Manage testers (on your internal test playstore console)" from "Restrict access to email lists" to "Anyone you shared the link with can download", after accessing the link for the first time you should have access to it even if you switch back to "Restrict access to email lists".

Comment: Readers should note that this answer is referring to **Google Play Console > Setup > "Internal app sharing"**, which is *different* than **Google Play Console > Release > Testing > "Internal testing"**

Comment: Make sure to enable Internal App Sharing at General options after enabling Developer Mode for Play Store with the steps provided above.

Answer (score 8):

Ok so after trying multiple solutions the only solution which worked for me is-

1. First you need to open the invite link from your system not from
   the phone(for some reason the accept invitation button is not visible on
   phone).
2. Now you need to click the accept invitation button.
3. Now you need to authenticate and then you can install the app successfully.

Comment: I had to apply both postal_card and @shivam-yadav suggestions to make it work

Answer (score 4):

What fixed this to me was first joining on the web(copied link and opened from android) and then using the download link [image]

Comment: The same step fixed it for me. I had to send the "Join on the web" link that looks something like https://play.google.com/apps/internaltest/123456789 to my testers. 

Using that link, they actually joined the testing program. Afterwards they were able to install the app with the link that looks like https://play.google.com/apps/test/you_app/your_version.

I did not have to deactivate my email list restriction for it to work. It was really just the "invitation link" that fixed everything.

Comment: man your a life saver

Comment: i opened it on web(phone) and it showed a text saying app has been shared with you but and a button that takes me to the playstore where i am still getting stuck on loader loop,any idea?

Comment: Same fixed for me

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to explicitly set who can download & install shared apps (in GooglePlay Console). By default no item was selected...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This issue happens when the option on your testers email list hasn't been checked.

Assuming that you already setup your email list:

Navigate to `Google Play Console > Setup > Internal app sharing`

Also, assuming that you want to restrict access to only your email list:

1. Check the `Restrict access to email lists` option
2. Go to the 'Email lists' tab and check all or specific emails you want to grant access.

Please see screenshots.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My issue was being logged into a different account on the Play Store on my Android device, vs the account that was logged in on the join programme invite popup from my email.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the tester accepts the invitation. This worked for me. Go to **Testing**  > **Internal testing** > **How testers join your test**. Click on **Copy link**, then you can share the link with the tester or open it on your device to accept the invitation. Then open the testing link again.
[image]